# How to Clear then Append URL with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to reload a page after a few seconds and append the URL with a variable containing new Lat Long coordinates. Consider the code snippet below that works with [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/):

```
 var latlng = getQueryVariable("latlng");

if(latlng){
  console.log(latlng); //working
}

function getQueryVariable(variable) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("?");

  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      return pair[1];
    }
  } 
  alert('Query Variable ' + variable + ' not found');
}

function onMapClick(e) {//Coordinate pop up
  popup.setLatLng(e.latlng)
       .setContent("Coordinates clicked are: " + e.latlng.toString())
       .openOn(map);

  var centerPoint = map.getSize().divideBy(2),
    targetPoint = centerPoint.subtract([1500, 0]),
    targetLatLng = map.containerPointToLatLng(centerPoint), //retrieve new lat longs
    loadLatlng = "?latlng="+targetLatLng.lat+","+targetLatLng.lng;


  setTimeout(function(){
     //And herein lies the problem - the URL is being concatenated ??
     window.location.href = window.location.href + loadLatlng;
     window.location.href.reload(1);
  }, 5000); 
}
```

Does anyone know how to clear and then append the URL?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to reload the page ? is not your purpose only to change the URL in the browser ?

Comment: I am reloading the page because in my app there is quite a bit of data stored in memory in the form of a JSON object (geometry and stats etc). So, I figure I would just reload the page and take the user back to where they were. It is a bit crude, but I'm not sure what else to do about memory leaking in the browser. Reloading the page does clear memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build the url using the parts

```
window.location.href = [location.protocol, '//', location.host, location.pathname,  loadLatlng].join("");
```

Same thing as

```
window.location.href = location.protocol +  '//' + location.host + location.pathname +  loadLatlng;
```

You could also do it a dirty way with splitting the current url on the `?`

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.split("?")[0] +  loadLatlng;
```

Comment: Badass! Thanks so much. If you thought this might help someone else, I would appreciate the thumbs up ;).